# instance variable life initiailized inside a method/thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the following code

package test;

```
public class TestRun implements Runnable {

    String message = new String("1111");

    public void run() {


        this.message="this is my message"+Thread.currentThread().getName();

        for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            try {
                Thread.sleep((new Double(Math.random()*10000 +1)).longValue());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        System.out.println(i +"this is message from thread"  + Thread.currentThread().getName() +" ====> " + message);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {

        (new Thread(new TestRun())).start();
        Thread.sleep((new Double(Math.random()*10000 +1)).longValue());
        (new Thread(new TestRun())).start();
        Thread.sleep((new Double(Math.random()*10000 +1)).longValue());  
        (new Thread(new TestRun())).start();

    }
}
```

In this code, I was expecting that last thread will overwrite the message string and all the thread should start printing the same message (initialized last), however when i run the code, it seems each thread keep value for its own message variable and print it. Is my understanding wrong here ?

Comment: Your understanding is so wrong that you shouldn't even be looking at threads yet.

Comment: the behavior you're looking for is achieved by adding both `virtual` and `static` keyword to the declaration of `message`, but this is something, we usually do **not** want.

Comment: i´m with @Kayaman. The topic, why each thread will print it´s own method, should be handled in a `Classes` tutorial, where you get taught about instance variables and class instances . Rephrasing the question here, it would generally be `Why does each instance of a class hold it´s own values for instance variables`, which is a rather basic question.

Comment: The `new String("1111");` and `(new Double(Math.random()*10000 +1)).longValue();` parts are also all too telling. Plenty to learn before delving into threading.

Answer (score 0):

You create three `TestRun` objects and each object has it's own field. This is a basic concept about objects, not a more advanced topic like how to work with multiple threads. If you want to shared data between threads, I suggest using a thread safe shared object.  e.g.

```
AtomicReference<String> message = new AtomicReference<>();
new Thread(new TestRun(message))).start();
Thread.sleep(200);
new Thread(new TestRun(message))).start();
Thread.sleep(200);
new Thread(new TestRun(message))).start();
```

BTW You should just sleep for a fixed amount like `Thread.sleep(100);`